# Why is the command line not like a mini buffer in normal mode?

Tags: command-line

When typing in the command line, and one wishes to make a correction, I am aware one can press `^f` to bring up a cmdline mini buffer where one can use `normal` and `insert` mode.

But this make me wonder, why if you press escape in the command line, does it not go to normal mode for the command line?

...all you would have do is find a different hotkey for cancel the current command (since `<escape>` is now taken)

Comment: I’m not sure we can answer this—it is that way probably because vi was that way, and escape was used to cancel commands (in normal mode too).

Comment: ask Bill Joy ;)

Comment: `cnoremap <Esc> <C-F>` ?